# Best way to calculate max minus sum of random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

I am trying to calculate the following probability distribution:

$Max(X_1, X_2,..., X_n) - \frac{1}{n} \sum _{i=1} ^{n} {X_i}$.

$X_i$ are iid random variables whose pmf is $\frac{C_{i-1}}{2^{2i-1}}$, where $C_i$ are Catalan numbers. However, I am also interested in the general problem regardless of the specific distribution at hand, if that makes sense.

Of course, calculating the max function and the sum separately is not an option since they depend on the same variables. However, is this still true if the sum is replaced by a normal distribution (considering CLT). What is the best approach to go about it? Is there any literature on it? I haven't been able to find anything useful.

Comment: That looks like a heavy tailed distribution for $X_i$ and I think $P(X_i>k)=\frac{2k \choose k}{4^k}$ which for large $k$ is about $\frac1{\sqrt{\pi k}}$ so I suspect the mean is not finite

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Does it change anything wrt the objective I'd like to achieve?

Comment: So you cannot replace anything with a normal distribution.

Comment: You are right, I haven't thought about that. However, could that have been a viable option with another distribution? Does the dependence problem go away if the sum is replaced by a normal distribution?

Comment: I suspect that it does not go away with better behaved distributions but the interaction effect could get get smaller and you end up approaching the difference between a [Generalized extreme value distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) and a narrowing almost-independent normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks, the links doesn't appear to work though

Comment: In this case, I suspect that you have a positive probability of $\frac1{2^n}$ that all the $X_i=1$ in which case the max-mean difference is $0$, but typically the distribution of the max-mean difference is not far from the distribution of the maximum.